# Controls added dynamically don't persist

Tags: asp.net

I have this panel...

```
<asp:Panel ID="panSumarios" runat="server" style="border:0px solid red;width:100%" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:Panel>
```

...inside a div associated to a ModalPopupExtender.

Then, on a button click, I add some controls (textboxes) dinamically to this panel. When I close (confirm) the ModalPopupExtender, I try to access this textboxes with no luck. They don't exist. It seems they do not persist after postback (when I confirm ModalPopupExtender).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well the postback will reload the page, as you say, and potentially nuke any custom controls you've added.  What code do you have on Load/PreLoad/PreRender etc.?

Comment: You have to recreate the textboxes on postback. Store the number of created controls in ViewState and add them with the same ID(derivable from the counter, f.e. `"TextBox_" + counter`) in Page_Init.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are a few things going on here. the biggest is confusing html controls with webforms server controls. another factor, if the added controls are web forms server controls, is when the dynamic controls are added.

dynamic webforms server controls must be created in the Init event to be properly wired to viewstate. they must also be created on every request.

Comment: Well, let me clarify this situation. I have a gridview with a checkbox column and some records in it . I also have a button which when I click, it opens a ModalPopupExtender with this panel inside it. Based on whick rows are checked (N) on the gridview, the button adds 1 textbox, 1 checkbox and a label multiply by N. 
Button also set some properties to this controls. How can I recreate them again in Page_Init?

Comment: you wouldn't. instead I would create a user control for each type of row. then show/hide the usercontrol(s) in the modal that pertain to the row.

Comment: `they must also be created on every request.` - bold that line.  Shout it from the rooftops - **they must also be created on every request.** +1 btw

Comment: only for dyanmics. in my solution the use controls are added at design time. visibility is controlled at runtime.

Comment: Thank you all. I finnaly did it. Based on a session variable, I recreate these controls on page_init, if postback. Best regards.